# listing core data attributes in a text field with swift

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, textview

I'm thinking this shouldn't be to hard, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone tell me how to list all the data stored under a given attribute in a text field for the user to manipulate?

Right now I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bodyTextView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //CoreData
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    var results: NSArray = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!

    var logsArray = [""]

    for res in results {
        var totalWorkTimeInHours = res.valueForKey("totalWorkTimeInHours") as Double
        var totalWorkTimeInHoursString = res.valueForkey("totalWorkTimeInHours") as String

        logsArray.append(totalWorkTimeInHoursString)

        bodyTextView.text = "Total hours worked:\n\(totalHoursWorkedSum) hours\n\nHour logs:\n\(logsArray)"

    }

}
```

In this code I'm trying to add all the doubles in the "totalWorkTimeInHours" attribute to the "bodyTextView.text" by bringing them in as strings and appending them to the "logsArray" but when I run it crashes. What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure it has something to do with the fact that "totalWorkTimeInHours" is an array of NSManagedObject and not Doubles or Strings, but how to I write the code to accomplish my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Where's "totalHoursWorkedSum" in your code? It's in the string you're trying to add to your textview, but there's no corresponding variable.

Comment: oh, sorry, I just minimized the code to be concise for this question. totalHoursWorkedSum is working fine and it displays in the textView, but I'm not sure how to list out all of the items that it's summing.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I'll upload an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just recast the valueForKey as a String.  You need to convert the double value to a string.  Replace:

```
var totalWorkTimeInHoursString = res.valueForkey("totalWorkTimeInHours") as String
```

with

```
var totalWorkTimeInHoursString = "\(totalWorkTimeInHours)"
```